# Dreaded black screen in Ubuntu Studio Lunar Lobster

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

First post here and I;m a Ubuntu rookie. Trying get Ubuntu Studio working on my HP Workstation. It's on a dedicated hard drive and installed just fine and worked for a while.  THEN..out of nowhere when the screen timed out and turned to black it wouldnt come back. A reboot would bring it back.  Then I saw there was a new driver for my Nvidia k600 vid card (that was tested and said to work) and I thought oh great, this will fix it....It made things much worse...I cant get back into Ubuntu at all...just a black screen even after going through the stuff i found to try on the internet..like going to command line via emergency boot and live session and trying nomodeset. Nothing works...

anyone one have anything specific to Nvidia that may work. I have Ubuntu Studio also installed in a Lenovo laptop and i was able to fix all the quirks so far w. that.  any help other than a clean reinstall that likely wont solve this problem, thanks. Ed

I really cant afford to invest much more time in this project other than booting it up in emergency mode once in a while and install updates

Answer (score 1):

On my machine the screen didn't come up at all after upgrading to 23.04. I fixed it by removing the nvidia drivers and using the non-proprietary drivers (Nouveau).

To do that I used Alt-F2 to get a terminal login. From there, I followed the steps from https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-uninstall-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux

After that don't manage to start Vivaldi (my webbrowser) or Chrome, but Firefox works. Starting Vivaldi on the command line (just use 'vivaldi') it complains about the GPU ('GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.') which I suppose is a result of the above procedure.

I managed to start vivaldi by using 'vivaldi --no-xshm --no-sandbox' on the command line. Not sure how to start Chrome from the command line but I suppose the issue and solution may well be similar.

It's not perfect but at least you get to a usable desktop... Last time I was on the non-proprietary drivers they weren't very stable. Hopefully it's better now.

Comment: Thanks. Since I just put Ubuntu in, I just reinstalled and then told the system not to ever sleep and the screen not to time out. That's far from ideal and doesnt solve the problem, but everything works. Not sure if it is also a problem with our systems not properly waking from a sleep. Maybe the nividia driver is ok?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).